# WordNet integrated with ElasticSearch - How to add new synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, wordnet, synonym

I work with **ElasticSearch** version 1.2.3

I've integrated **WordNet 3.0** as a Synonym database for ElasticSearch Synonyms Analyzer. (Full WordNet install: configure, make, make install)

I've added the following code to the ElasticSearch index settings (the index name is **local_es**)

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/local_es/_settings' -d '{
"settings" : {
"analysis" : {
  "analyzer" : {
    "synonym" : {
    "tokenizer" : "lowercase",
    "filter" : ["synonym"]
    }
   },
   "filter" : {
   "synonym" : {
   "type" : "synonym",
   "format": "wordnet",
   "synonyms_path": "analysis/wn_s.pl"
   }
  }
 }
}
}'
```

I've also have updated the mapping with the following code:

```
enter code here
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/local_es/shadowpage/_mapping' -d '{
"shadowpage" : {
"shadowPageName" : {
  "enabled" : true,
  "analyzer" : "synonym"
},
"properties" : {                
"name" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "analyzer" : "synonym" }
}
}
}'
```

All is working as expected.

As you can see, ElasticSearch takes its data from the file path of analysis/**wn_s.pl**

wn_s.pl file is a WordNet prolog file that contains all the database synonyms.

How can I add new synonyms to the database?
Do I add it directly to the WordNet database? Or in **wn_s.pl** file?

Comment: It depends on whether that file gets updated when you add stuff to the database.

Comment: When you add entry to wn_s (properly), then added synonyms will be reflected in elasticsearch.

Comment: Is this is what I need to do, Why do I need a WordNet database installation? All I need is the wn_s file

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be actively modifying your synonym database you should probably just transform the synsets in the wordnet database into the basic comma delimited file in this format

```
    "british,english",
    "queen,monarch"
```

Then use and edit this file as your synonym resource.